# How to solve 'Uncaught ReferenceError: abp is not defined at Module../src/main.ts' error in Angular 6/7?

Tags: angular, typescript, aspnetboilerplate

I upgraded my Asp Net Zero template project from 2 to version 7 one by one. I have managed to run the application on Angular version 5 without much effort. However, after I upgraded the client project of the app to the Angular 7, I am getting this error at the start of the app;

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: abp is not defined
    at Module../src/main.ts (main.js:56933)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime.js:79)
    at Object.0 (main.js:112364)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime.js:79)
    at checkDeferredModules (runtime.js:46)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (runtime.js:33)
    at main.js:1
```

I followed the steps that Angular update tool suggested here;
https://update.angular.io/. Angular created the angular.json file and made the necessary changes throughout the client project. I only commented out 'LocalForage' package section in the typing.d.ts file because there was an error about multiple extends on this library. I think LocalForage added its own typing to its own folder inside the node_modules and it was conflicting with this file.

I haven't made any changes on main.ts file but made several changes to 'tsconfig.json' file. These are 'main.ts' and 'tsconfig.ts' files respectively;

```
import './polyfills.ts';

import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { AccountModule } from './account/account.module';
import { AppConsts } from './shared/AppConsts';
import { AppPreBootstrap } from './AppPreBootstrap';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

import * as moment from 'moment';

import 'moment/min/locales.min';
import 'moment-timezone';

if (environment.production) {
    enableProdMode();
}

abp.ui.setBusy();
AppPreBootstrap.run(() => {
    if (abp.session.userId) {
        AppPreBootstrap.bootstrap(AppModule).then(() => {
            abp.ui.clearBusy();
        });
    } else {
        $('body').attr('class', 'page-md login');
        AppPreBootstrap.bootstrap(AccountModule).then(() => {
            abp.ui.clearBusy();
        });
    }
});

//A workaround to make angular-cli finding the startup module!
var b = false; if (b) { platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AccountModule); }
```

```
{
  "include": [
    "../src/**/*",
    "../node_modules/abp-ng2-module/src/**/*",
    "../node_modules/abp-web-resources/Abp/Framework/scripts/**/*" // This line doesn't make any difference. Tried with commented out as well.
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es6", "dom" ],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@abp/*": [ "../node_modules/abp-ng2-module/dist/src/*" ],
      // "@abp/*": [ "../node_modules/abp-ng2-module/src/*" ],
      "@app/*": ["./app/*"],
      "@shared/*": ["./shared/*"],
      "@node_modules/*": ["../node_modules/*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

I have added 'include' and 'exclude' parts according to GitHub issues that I saw in the project repo. I also tried the commented version of those parts in case the problem occurs from them but I think it is not relevant. I have also tried the app with '"@abp/*": [ "../node_modules/abp-ng2-module/dist/src/*" ],' line with and without the dist folder inside the paths.

When I go to the definition of 'abp', I can navigate to abp.d.ts file inside 'abp-web-resources' package which is included inside the node_modules folder of the application. So there is no error while compilation process. I got the error when type 'localhost:4200' to the browser. I have added several gist links in case anyone wants to check out the changed parts because I was able to run the application properly on Angular 5. I have not much experience on latest versions of the Angular. My guess is, I need to change something about referencing node packages inside the application and I believe this won't be the only error that I will get on runtime. Thanks in advance.

### Gist links

package.json - Angular 7: https://gist.github.com/alpersilistre/b83483cf84ff7530f684fa4f387dd573
package.json - Angular 5: https://gist.github.com/alpersilistre/7e5c31fb8617564c113c882cb2930896

angular.json - Angular 7: https://gist.github.com/alpersilistre/6eb901f1754339f48a52cbb7a77445ce
angular-cli.json - Angular 5: https://gist.github.com/alpersilistre/13098f660baaa6327ec4c246eef59f2a

Comment: have you try `declare const abp;`

Comment: @Abhishek Do you mean inside the main.ts file? Yes, I tried and still the same error.

Comment: `abp.ui.setBusy();` why you are using this in main.ts

Comment: @Abhishek I wasn't made that choice and don't know if its right place to call :) Block UI show the loading on the page and then AppModule or AccountModule is getting called according to the availability of the userId which is an indicator of the logged in user.

Comment: Also asked in [aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template#395](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/issues/395).